# Handling migration in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This was my original Schema

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({  
    attachments: [String]
});
```

This is my updated Schema

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({  
    attachments: [{
        fileType: String,
        extension: String,
        url: String
    }]
});
```

Do I really have to create another model with the old Schema to find() the old documents and process the attachments and then using the updated schema model to save the document in order to successfully migrate my collection to the new Schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually rename legacy field in the mongo shell: `db.message.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "attachments": "attachments_v1" } } );` and use

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    attachments_v1: [String],  
    attachments: [{
        fileType: String,
        extension: String,
        url: String
    }]
});
```

with transition logic for some time to spread the load and modify the documents when they are being accessed. If the collection is small enough you can convert all of then in one go. If transition logic is trivial you may be able to do it from the shell. Otherwise, write a mongoose script to do the job.

Comment: i've also considered this solution.. but i think this is longer to make as I have to add a field, then process the collection, and then deleting the field

Comment: Sure, the question was *Do I really have to*, the answer is No. There are other options. Which one to pick depends on many factors, most important are the transformation logic, size of the collection, acceptable downtime etc.